# Unable to connect to remote Cassandra via Spark + Scala

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm having some troubles while trying to connect to a remote **Cassandra** using **Apache-Spark** and **Scala**. I successfully managed to connect in past, in the same way, with **MongoDb**.

This time I really don't understand why I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {127.0.0.1}:9042

I guess it's a dependency and version problem but I was not able to find anything related to this issue in particular, both on documentation and on other questions.

I essentially manage to connect via ssh-tunnel to my server using [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) and all works fine. Then, I'm successfully able to connect to the local apache-spark using **SparkConnectionFactory.scala**:

```
package connection

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

class SparkConnectionFactory {

  var sparkContext : SparkContext = _

  def initSparkConnection = {
    val configuration = new SparkConf(true).setMaster("local[8]")
                        .setAppName("my_test")
                        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
                        .set("spark.cassandra.input.consistency.level","ONE")
                        .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
    val sc = new SparkContext(configuration)
    sparkContext = sc
  }

  def getSparkInstance : SparkContext = {
    sparkContext
  }

}
```

And calling it in my **Main.scala**:

```
val sparkConnectionFactory = new SparkConnectionFactory
sparkConnectionFactory.initSparkConnection
val sc : SparkContext = sparkConnectionFactory.getSparkInstance
```

But, when I try to select all the items inside a Cassandra table using:

```
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("my_keyspace", "my_table")
rdd.foreach(println)
```

I get the error I wrote above.

On my server I installed `Scala ~v2.11.6`, `Spark ~v2.1.1`, `SparkSQL ~v2.1.1`. Of course I have 8 cores and a replication factor of 1. On my `pom.xml` I have:

```
. . .
<properties>
    <scala.version>2.11.6</scala.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    . . .

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**Is my issue caused by conflicting versions? If yes, how can I fix this? If not, any hint on what's causing it?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: at {127.0.0.1}:9042 would be connection to localhost, not remote

Comment: @cricket_007 No, as I stated above, I'm connected to the server using jsch. When you do it, then, you access everything from localhost. I'm able to use spark, mongo and many more tools and services like this.

Comment: Then you are not forwarding the correct port over SSH

Comment: I'm forwarding port `9042` to `8988`.

Comment: Okay, then your error specifically says it's trying to connect to localhost 9042, and not 8988, so either forward your local port to the same remote one, or add in the port to your configuration

Comment: You are probably right. Setting forward_port to 9042 anyways leads to the same problem.

Comment: Then you should debug on the server side to check Cassandra’s bind address and firewalls, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm forwarding port 9042 to 8988

Then that's the port you need to connect to

```
.set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", 8988)
```